# I can't connect to the hotspot on Linux Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: 23.10, hot-spot

I can't connect to my hotspot created on Linux Ubuntu 23.10.
Now my cell phone appears, I turn it on and it says that it cannot be connected to that network.